# I want to copy this file but i cant type it correctly in the terminal

Tags: file, unix, terminal, copy, command

```
/path/of/the/file/  EveLYN !!!!! BereZIN $$ $0
```

I've wrote it like this but it didnt work: `"  EveLYN !!!!! BereZIN $$ $0"`
It's supposed to be .tar file.

Comment: Perhaps `cp *EveLYN* otherfile` (check other files in directory).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your double quotes to single quotes.

This:

```
"  EveLYN !!!!! BereZIN $$ $0"
```

Becomes this:

```
'  EveLYN !!!!! BereZIN $$ $0'
```

Certain special characters within double quotes (in your case the `$`) will be interpreted by the command line. So it will try to take anything that starts with a `$` and replace it with the value of a variable. If you use single quotes, you're telling the command line to use exactly what you have between the single quotes, don't do anything with it. It's just a literal string.

Comment: Additionally, `!` triggers history expansion. This filename is almost designed to be as annoying to handle as possible.